# WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/...' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sockets, socket.io, react-functional-component

I am trying to create a chat app which, uses a real-time database with MongoDB and Websocket.
This is my first React, MongoDB, and Websocket Project, so please excuse possible trivialities. :D

I am currently working on creating a new user, refreshing the database, and finally displaying the created user in every user's frontend in real-time.

Creating and saving a new user works fine and also logging the new user's data in real-time after the database changed (via socket.io) is working as well. Now, I would like to access the information that the database changed in the frontend of my app, so I can refresh the unordered list of users. 
 Now there is the problem I'd like to solve: 
 I try to connect the frontend with my backend by using this code:

```
//...

import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "localhost:5000";

const MainContentArea = () => {

   useEffect(()=>{
       const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT);
       socket.on("changes", data => {
           console.log(data);
       })
   });

//...
```

The following is my backend code:

```
const express = require('express');
const http = require('http');
const socketIo = require('socket.io');
const index = require('./routes/index');
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const app = express();
app.use(index);

const server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server ist running on port: ${port}`);
})
const io = socketIo(server).listen(server);

const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

require('dotenv').config({
    path: './.env'
});

const Users = require('./models/user.model');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());

const usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

app.use('/users', usersRouter);

const uri = process.env.ATLAS_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, {
    
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true

}, 

function(err){
    if(err){
        console.log("server.js err line 44");
        throw err;
    }

    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
        console.log('user connected');
        socket.on('disconnect', (socket) => {
            console.log('user disconnected');
        })
    })
    Users.watch().on('change', (change) => {
        console.log('socket says: something changed in db');
        console.log('change: ', change.fullDocument);
        io.to(change.fullDocument).emit('changes',change.fullDocument)
    })
}
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;
connection.once('open', () => {
    console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
})
```

I keep getting the Error message: 
`WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:5000/socket.io/? EIO=3&transport=websocket&sid=33wU6D8PnqclT3iZAAAB' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`

I am using Chrome and I am working on MacOS.

I am very thankful for any suggestions that might help solve my problem.

I hope, how I posted my question is helpful for anybody who is willing to help me with this. If not, feel free to give me suggestions on what to do better next time! This is my first post here.